# Damaged Pdf after setting content from a server response

Tags: java, pdf, byte, documentum

I am currently making rest calls to a server for signing a pdf document.

I am sending a pdf(binary content) and retrieving the binary content of the signed pdf.
When i get the binary content from the inputStream:

```
    try (InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream()) {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
                String lines;
                while ((lines = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    output += lines;
                }
            }
        }
    }

signedPdf.setBinaryContent(output.getBytes());
```

(signedPdf is a DTO with byte[] attribute)
but when i try to set the content of the pdf with the content of the response pdf:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
out.write(signedPdf);
pdf.setContent(signedPdf);
```

and try to open it, it says that the pdf is damaged and cannot be repaired.

Anyone encountered something similar? Do i need to set the content-length as well for the output stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF is *binary data*. One corrupts the PDF when reading as *text* (which in Java is always Unicode).
Also it is a waste: a byte as char would double the memory usages, and
there are two conversions: from bytes to String and vice versa, using some encoding.
When converting from UTF-8 even UTF-8 format errors may be raised.

```
try (InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream()) {
    if (inputStream != null) {
        byte[] content = inputStream.readAllBytes();
        signedPdf.setBinaryContent(content);
    }
}
```

Whether to use a `BufferedInputStream` depends, for instance on the expected PDF size.

Furthermore `new String(byte[], Charset)` and `String.getBytes(Charset)` **with explicit Charset** (like `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`) are preferable over a default Charset overloaded version. Those use the current platform encoding, and hence delivers non-portable code. Behaving differently on an other platform/computer.

Comment: Million thanks! Saving it to string was causing the problem.